# Filter a query based on a Text Box value in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form in Excel with two TextBoxes. I’m trying to get the value from those TextBoxes as query criteria in VBA Excel. 
I have tried different ways to achieve this, but it just doesn't work.

Thanks! Here is the code.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
         "FROM reporte_fallas.reportefallas reportefallas_0 " & _
         "WHERE (reportefallas_0.CREADT BETWEEN [Forms]![QueryUserForm]![StartDateTextBox] AND [Forms]![QueryUserForm]![EndDateTextBox])"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following answer:

[How to add parameters to an external data query in Excel which can't be displayed graphically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091908/how-to-add-parameters-to-an-external-data-query-in-excel-which-cant-be-displaye)

Another idea could be to use a DAO or ADO recordset, if you're connecting to external data.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked this before I posted: Are you using ADO or DAO for your query?

Comment: I have an ODBC Connection

Comment: Sorry, please see my amended answer