# Use MS Query in Excel 2010 to Get Data from SQL Server Using Parameters-Complex Query Using Between Two Dates

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-query

I tried working with the solutions noted in [Excel: Use a cell value as a parameter for a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query) and [How to add parameters to an external data query in Excel which can't be displayed graphically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091908/how-to-add-parameters-to-an-external-data-query-in-excel-which-cant-be-displaye).  However, I can't get any of the solutions to work.

Below is a segment that I am having trouble with.  There are multiple tables in the query.  I pasted the SQL in the Command text in the Definition tab of the Connection Properties window.  I have no problems when I enter the dates as they are below.  However, I get a message about converting date and/or time from character string when I replace the dates with question marks.  If I do the same and exclude the quote marks, I get a message about invalid parameter number.

I'm thinking that I should try to programatically update the connection file because I can't figure out how to acheive what I want to do any other way.

```
AND CAST(EXITED_FROM_ACTIVITY_DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-01'
```

Comment: What happens if you also cast the parameters as dates?

Comment: I don't know.  I've given up on that method.  It seems like it is going to be too difficult to do with to many exceptions.  I used the macro recorder when creating a MS Query.  Here is some information on the Query Table object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use date format as in query like this:

```
TO_CHAR(A.JOURNAL_DATE ,'YYYYMM') >='201506' and TO_CHAR(A.JOURNAL_DATE ,'YYYYMM') <='201506'
```

and can give parameters as `201501 1` can be extended period 1 to 12