# Add Data From Cells To Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, excel, refresh, excel-2013

In Excel 2013 I am embedding a SQL Server query into my workbook so that it may be refreshable.  If I click the Data Tab then From Other Sources then choose SQL Server and input my query (just for example sake)

```
Select Top 1 employeename 
from employees
Where hiredate between A1 AND A2
```

And in A1 the value 04/10/2016 is entered and in A2 the value 04/15/2016 is entered.  How would I read the value from the cells into my where clause?

Answer (score 0):

In order to read data from the workbook for use as a parameter in a query you need to import your data using Microsoft query.

Please refer to the forum post here for more information.

[How to add parameters to an external data query in Excel which can't be displayed graphically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091908/how-to-add-parameters-to-an-external-data-query-in-excel-which-cant-be-displaye)

Comment: This can only be achieved using Microsoft Query, not using the SQL Server option?