# Using Excel VBA to insert multiple values into a connection query

Tags: sql, vba, excel, t-sql

I have a working Excel spreadsheet which uses VBA to change a parameter in the connection query depending on what is entered into a single cell.  It cannot use an Excel Parameter to pick up the value because the variable is in the join not in the where part of the query.  So I know this works in principle, at least for one cell of data.

I now need to create a new spreadsheet where I need to put a range of data into the query.

The query looks something like this:

**Select 
* 
FROM TABLE_A
Where ID in 
('A',
'B',
'C')**

The VBA picks up the values A, B and C from a column in the spreadsheet, and currently looks like this:

```
Dim ID_Range As Range
Sheets("Data").Select
Set ID_Range = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A10")
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Database_A").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "Select * FROM Table_A A WHERE A.ID in " "(" + ID_Range + ")")
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .Connection = Array(Array( _
    ODBC;Description= ****
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .SourceDataFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
```

I hope I haven't removed any important code when removing the company specific information.
When this is run it comes up with the error:  **Subscript out of Range**.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45616221/8411349

Comment: "Select * FROM Table_A A WHERE ..."
Surplus A after Table_A?

Comment: That looks promising, thanks!  I'll test it now.

Comment: Your `.Connection` uses arrays whose parenthesis are not closed

Comment: Do you HAVE to use an ODBC connection object ? Or does another solution that quickly pulls the data from your backend suit as well ?

Comment: @User91504 - Yes, tested that method and that works fine, thank you!

peakpeak and Patrik Honorez - I chopped up my actual query to remove actual database and table names.  Looks like I did a messy job.  The query works, I was just trying to show the bit that didn't.

Patrick Honorez ODBC question - I'm an old dog, ODBC is how I've always connected to SQL databases from Excel, Access etc.  Is there a better solution these days?

Comment: @MattHollands glad it worked, I find it's a very easy method to add many parameters into a query linked through excel cells

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
Dim ID_Range As Range
Dim vR() As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim strRange  As String
Sheets("Data").Select
Set ID_Range = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A10")
For Each Rng In ID_Range
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
    vR(n) = "'" & Rng & "'"
Next Rng
strRange = Join(vR, ",")

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from Database_A").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array("Select * FROM Table_A A WHERE A.ID in (" & strRange & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific need of the ODBCConnection object (and I don't see its advantage in your situation) you can do this quite simply using ADODB or even good old DAO!

```
' Create a recordset object.Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
' Assign the Connection object.
.ActiveConnection = cnPubs
' Extract the required records.
.Open "SELECT * FROM Authors"
' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

' Tidy up
.Close
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing
```

(code sample pasted from https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/306125/how-to-import-data-from-microsoft-sql-server-into-microsoft-excel)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a function to process the range

```
Function getCommaSeparatedList(Source As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim results As String
    For Each cell In Source
        results = results & "'" & cell.Value & "',"
    Next
    getCommaSeparatedList = Left(results, Len(results) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, That's part of the solution used in the link that User91504 sent in the previous comment.